# Convert string to datetime - 'Feb' month not parsed

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a series of string objects in the following format:

```
lcd['dates'] = ['Sep-2014', 'Feb-2014', 'Apr-2014', 'Oct-2013', 'Oct-2014',...]
```

I am trying to convert them to a date time format (rounded to days) as follows:

```
lcd['new dates'] = [pd.to_datetime(j, unit = "D",exact=False) for j in lcd.dates]
```

This seems to work for all months save Feb:

```
In: lcd['new_dates'].unique():

Out:Timestamp('2013-05-29 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2015-03-29 00:00:00'),
   Timestamp('2012-06-29 00:00:00'), 'Feb-2015',
   Timestamp('2012-12-29 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-07-29 00:00:00'),
   Timestamp('2014-09-29 00:00:00'), 'Feb-2014',...
```

I'm stumped.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the format as such:

```
import pandas as pd

lcd = ['Sep-2014', 'Feb-2014', 'Feb-2015', 'Apr-2014', 'Oct-2013', 'Oct-2014',]
lcd = [pd.to_datetime(j, unit = "D", format='%b-%Y') for j in lcd]
print lcd
```

Prints:

```
[Timestamp('2014-09-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-02-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2015-02-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-04-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2013-10-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-10-01 00:00:00')]
```

Also to see all format options for [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 2):

to_datetime() has a format argument, which should force it to interpret it in a particular way. I bet the reason February is failing is because today is the 29th, which is (usually) not okay for February. (Note the other dates have the 29th in them. I guess it's replacing the unspecified day with the current day for some reason.)

Comment: Yup. The dateutil library is used internally, which will attempt to fill in missing date components with the current ones. So: datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 30, 0, 0) is the result of parsing just "March" (default year and day)

Answer (score 1):

Data like this reads nicely using `Period`. You can always convert to timestamps if you wish (and control how it is converted, e.g. first or last day-of-month).

```
In [1]: PeriodIndex([ Period(p,'M') for p in ['Sep-2014', 'Feb-2014', 'Apr-2014', 'Oct-2013', 'Oct-2014'] ])
Out[1]: PeriodIndex(['2014-09', '2014-02', '2014-04', '2013-10', '2014-10'], dtype='int64', freq='M')

In [2]: PeriodIndex([ Period(p,'M') for p in ['Sep-2014', 'Feb-2014', 'Apr-2014', 'Oct-2013', 'Oct-2014'] ]).to_timestamp()
Out[2]: DatetimeIndex(['2014-09-01', '2014-02-01', '2014-04-01', '2013-10-01', '2014-10-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None, tz=None)
```

This is briefly mentioned [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5886)

Comment: Just to make things more explicit: `Period(p, 'M')` describes a period of *one month* (starting on the first day of `p`)—it does not instruct Pandas to parse a "month"+year format. Reference: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#period.